# Wave against a conducting sphere within a sphere

Tags: electromagnetism

Let's say you had a wave from a distant source hitting a sphere/ball inside a shell, both made of a good conductor, with the charge on the center sphere/ball held constant by some means, as in the below set-up:
[image]

Would the wave have any effect on (my questions and my attempt at answering them):

1. The **E** field inside the shell? I'd guess not due to Gauss's law - the charge inside the shell is fixed, so the E field would have to be fixed too.
2. The **B** field inside the shell? Not sure, I think Ampere's is the most relevant here: the **E** field would be fixed, but the wave would create **J** on the surface of the exterior shell. I'm not sure if that'd affect **B** inside it though.
3. The magnetic vector potential **A** inside the shell? Possibly...depends on the answer to (2).
4. The scalar electric potential $\phi$ inside the shell? Depends, if the **E** field is static, but if the **A** field is not, then $\phi$ would change inside the shell: $\textbf{E}=-\nabla \phi-\frac{\partial \textbf{A}}{\partial t}$

Comment: Yes, it is absolutely possible to excite a metal sphere with the right frequency so that there is a strong electromagnetic field inside. This is exactly what happens with accelerator cavities. See e.g. https://people.nscl.msu.edu/~haoy/teaching/fundamental_AP/longitudinal_dynamics/longitudinal_dynamics.html for a picture.